# IOS FBSDK No UserAccessToken

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I have read many posts here about how to get the users info after they log in.  But my onProfileUpdated function is never being triggered even though the login is successful

Here is my ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "backLogin_Blur.jpg")!)

        if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
        {   // Already logged in on this device
            println("Already logged in as: " + FBSDKProfile.currentProfile().firstName + " " + FBSDKProfile.currentProfile().lastName)
        } else {
            println("Not logged in")
            var loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
            loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile"]
            loginButton.center = self.view.center
            loginButton.delegate = self

            FBSDKProfile.enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true)
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "onProfileUpdated:", name: FBSDKProfileDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

            self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        println("View Appeared")
        if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
        {
            //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showPicSelector", sender: self)
        }
    }

    //Facebook Login:
    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
        if(error == nil) // Success
        {
            println("Login Complete")

            //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showPicSelector", sender: self)
        }else if result.isCancelled { // User Cancelled
            println("Cancelled")
        }else {
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        println("User Logged Out")
    }

    func onProfileUpdated(notfication: NSNotification){
        println("onProfileUpdated Triggered!")
        if(FBSDKProfile.currentProfile() != nil) {
            println(FBSDKProfile.currentProfile().firstName + " " + FBSDKProfile.currentProfile().lastName)
            println(FBSDKProfile.currentProfile().userID)
        }
    }

}
```

I have created a simple singleview application in iOS swift.  I get the messaged that the login was completed, but the User's Profile is never updated, so I can never get the users information.

Comment: Which version of the Facebook iOS SDK are you using? 4.4?

Comment: Yes, I just grabbed ge latest version a few weeks ago.